# How to retrive url of the first post in blogger blogspot?

Tags: url, post, get, blogger, blogspot

I notice there is a data tag condition, 'data:post.isFirstPost' to check whether a post is first post or not. But what I wanted is not to check, but to get the url of very first post, so I can link that url to an image in homepage.

Like 'data:blog.homepageUrl' for home page, is there a url for the first post in blogger? If not, is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct blogger tag for first post URL, But you can get it inside blog posts widget by this condition

```
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
        <img src='sdf.jpg'/>
    </a>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I did wrong here please. Linking image vanished when it was wrapped like below.                                                                                                      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>        <data:post.url/>                                                                                             <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
<img src='sdf.jpg'/></a>                                                                                      </b:if>
</b:loop>

Comment: I used a valid source for image. I just edited it here to shorten code.

Comment: I have tried your code works fine. you can use it only inside blog widget main `<b:includable id='main' var='top'>`. But if you want to use it inside `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` remove loop tag `<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'><a expr:href='data:post.url'><img src='sdf.jpg'/></a></b:if>`. I will update my answer.